# Finding the slopes of the sides of an equilateral triangle, when given only two points

Tags: geometry

I want to find the slopes of an equilateral triangle, when given only the two vertices. Let's say they are $(0,0)$ and $(5,5)$. Graphing this would give two triangles forming a diamond. I tried to use the distance formula to get the other sides, but I can't get it. Someone told me that I don't need to get the two other sides to get the slopes. He told me to use study angle of inclination. How could I solve this one by applying the angle of inclination?

The slope of the line formed by the two points could be easily solved by using the slope formula which results to $1$, but I couldn't get the others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an image of the situation:

[image: Equilateral triangles]

Two methods for finding the slope are:

- Use [Pythagoras' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to find $x$, and $\text{rise}/\text{run}$ to find the slopes.
- Recognize that $\theta$ is $60$ degrees (since we have an equilateral tringle).  Then use [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) ([SOHCAHTOA](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SOHCAHTOA.html)) to find $x$, and $\text{rise}/\text{run}$ to find the slopes.

Comment: what tool you used for the diagram?

Comment: I drew it in tikz, a LaTeX package.

Answer (score 0):

Let the slope of one side of the equilateral triangle be $m = \tan \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of inclination.

Then, the other two sides have slopes of $\tan(\theta + 60^{\circ})$ and $\tan(\theta - 60^{\circ})$. (Do you see why?)

In your problem, the segment from $(0,5)$ to $(5,5)$ has slope $m = 0$, and so $\theta = 0$.

Therefore, the other two sides have slopes of $\tan(60^{\circ})$ and $\tan(-60^{\circ})$.

We can generalize the problem to the case where the slope of the given segment is $m = \tan \theta$, then the other two sides would have slopes of $\tan(\theta \pm 60^{\circ}) = \dfrac{\tan \theta \pm \tan 60^{\circ}}{1 \mp \tan\theta \tan 60^{\circ}} = \dfrac{m \pm \sqrt{3}}{1 \mp m\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: i cant understand the theta+60 and theta-60

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to find the third vertex.  Let the third vertex be $(x,y.)$

Distance between $(0,0)$$(5,5)$: $d=\sqrt{(5-0)^2+(5-0)^2}=5\sqrt2$

Distance between $(x,y)$ and $(0,0)$ you get $x^2+y^2=50$...(I)

Distance between $(x,y)$ and $(5,5)$ you get $(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2=50$...(II)

Solving (I) and (II) will give you two values of $y=\frac{\Large5}{\Large2}(1\pm\sqrt3)$ and two values for $x$.

Now with all the three vertices known you can find slope of each side.

OR, find $\tan(45), -\tan(15), -\tan(105)$ to get all three slopes.
[image]

Comment: I get this solution but how could i prove that the angle is 15?

Comment: @daniel, the line from (0,0) to (5,5) is y=x with slope=1, which means it makes 45 degree angle with positive X-axis and total angle made by two sides at (0,0) is 60, 60-45=15 gives you the angle made by the side with positive X-axis

Comment: @daniel, tan (45)=1